# How to test videos for artifacts?

Tags: video, visual-artifacts

I am having some issues with videos where the encoding gets choppy for a stretch: frames jumping back and forth, pixels bleeding from one frame into another. Like in [this video right there](http://youtu.be/Hdt47bIM5pk?t=21m42s).

I know this is an encoding problem because it shows on the original video on different players and different machines (and sometimes this type of artifact does not show on raw footage). I was wondering, is there a way to auto-identify such places? Perhaps have an output as a list of timecodes where this stuff is happening so that I could go straight to editing? Run a dozen videos at a time through a script or some such and see if there are major problems with any.

Comment: Virtual Dub has in it "Scan video stream for errors", but it only finds the worst of the problems. It could be from the original raw footage, even if not easily seen, as minor data errors when encoded could become total messes. When it is how specific players and codecs work it can be special compression tricks used in the encoding process that are not compatable with the players or the codec used to decode it. Sometime it can help to have less encoding tricks selected in the "advanced" features of the codec. They do have progams that detect data damaged MP3s, a method for video would be great